# Open whatsapp app from a link in a mobile web site?

Tags: hyperlink, whatsapp

Is there any way to open whatsapp application from a website being in a mobile? I know if you use `whatsapp://` you can open whatsapp app, but how can I open whatsapp and create a new conversation with a given number? is it possible? thank you!

Comment: Probably helpful: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/?category=5245251

Comment: You can share text with whatsapp

Comment: whatsapp://send?text=your_text_here

Comment: Anyone knows if it´s possible to open whatsapp with an image (maybe the base64) instead of text?

Answer (score 21):

Thanks to the comments, I got my solution from them: `whatsapp://send?phone=XXXXXXX`

So for an spanish number +34 644 789 83 it would be

```
whatsapp://send?phone=3464478983
```

Answer (score 17):

**api.whatsapp.com** works well too. Use it in the same way, delete the (+) symbol and spaces in the telephone number.

```html
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=50600000000">Click to connect +506 0000 0000</a>
```

Answer (score 7):

Solution above is working good, but for me i prefer to use both of mobile app and web.

---

You can use it like this (empty chat):

```
<p>My whatsapp +1 987654321 <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=0000000000">Web</a> | <a href="whatsapp://send?phone=0000000000">App</a></p>
```

And you can use it like this (with chat text):

```
<p>My whatsapp +1 987654321 <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=0000000000&text=example">Web</a> | <a href="whatsapp://send?phone=0000000000&text=example">App</a></p>
```

This will give your visitors both way to contact you from PC browser or Mobile browser.

- change 0000000000 with your number, phone number should be with country code and without +
- change example with your own chat message

Answer (score 7):

This link in browser will open whatsapp aplication with chat conversation for the provided number

```
Wa.me/91xxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: is the domain wa.me registered by whatsapp? if not, might not be such a smart idea to pass your or other peoples phone numbers to some random website and even though wa.me redirects to whatsapp, anyone could do a forward to whatsapp. the whois data i found is inconclusive.

Comment: It is owned by Facebook/WhatsApp since it is mentioned in WhatsApp's Help Center: https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/chats/how-to-use-click-to-chat/?lang=en

Answer (score 4):

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+910000000000&text=Hi, I contacted you Through your website." class="social-icon whatsapp"></a>
```

For web-

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find a single link to attend PCs and mobiles. So, I had to choose between `https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=0000000000000` for PCs and `whatsapp://send?phone=0000000000000` for mobiles.

You must consider some things:

1. If you are in a mobile, you probably will want to open WhatsApp's app;
2. You you are in a PC, you probably will want to open WhatsApp Web;
3. You can have WhatsApp Desktop installed in your PC, so you probably will want to open WhatsApp there;
4. You can't know what is the current device in a reliable way.

So, the best option to me was to show a modal dialog questioning the user how WhatsApp should be opened (app or web).

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="https://wa.me/<<your_number>>?text=<<url_encoded_text>>"</a>`

example:
`<a href="https://wa.me/491793666167?text=Hi%20I%20am%20Samuel%20Demir"</a>`

**your_number: number in international_format:**
+491793666167 => 491793666167

**url_encoded_text: pre-fill-text:**
for space string enter %20
-> Hi I am Samuel Demir
-> Hi%20I%20am%20Samuel%20Demir